# will be doing vs will, be going to

Tags: word-usage, difference, tense, progressive-aspect, will-vs-going-to

I often hear the announcement on a train say

- "We will soon be arriving at XX station."

I understand the meaning of will, be going to, and will be doing.  However, I wonder why the announcement uses "will be arriving" instead of "will arrive" or "are going to arrive" though they would basically mean the same:

- "We will soon arrive at XX station."
- "We are going to arrive at XX station soon."

Maybe they sound awkward as an announcement.

Comment: Asking "how do you feel" and "do they sound awkward" requests opinions. Are you instead asking about which is correct, which is common, etc.?

Comment: No.  I am not asking which is correct.  I know that they all gramatically correct.  What I'd like to know is why the announcement chooses "will be arriving" instead of "will arrive" or "be going to arrive".  I'd like to know in what kind of situation "will be arriving" is commonly used.

Comment: You might say to your travelling companion "We're going to arrive at XX soon, so get your things packed up ready to change trains" - but _going to_ sounds too informal for an official announcement. I can't tell you why _will be arriving_ sounds more natural than _will arrive_ in this context - it just does!

Comment: How is this different from [your question two years ago](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/305588/whats-the-difference-between-we-will-soon-arrive-and-we-will-soon-be-arri)?

Comment: @kuwabara OK, I got rid of the other questions so that it focuses on why the author chose to write the verb that way.

Comment: "will be arriving" is used for planes, trains and buses because that it what they hope will happen. It means they are scheduled to arrive then or in that place.